# Display select tag options in list but hide text when select box is closed

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am using a select tag for a user to select a country from. When they select an option, I want to display the country code instead of the full country name. To do this, whenever a selection happens, the parent div of the select tag gets new class added to it where the content is the country code. The parent div also has a `selection` class added to it whenever an option is selected.

My issue is that I want to hide the selected option in the text field whenever an item is selected, but at the same time I want to be able to see the text in the list on a windows machine (select background is white) when I go to change my selection.

Is it possible for a select to only display the options in the list but not in the text field when closed?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to have a `<select>` field where the text shown for the "selected" option is different than what appears in the dropdown list of the `<select>` field?

If so, you could take advantage of the fact that a `<select>` element can be invisible but still display its dropdown `<option>` list normally. By styling your element with `<select style="position:absolute; opacity:0">` and positioning it over another element you want to use to display the "selected" value, you can display something different when an option is selected.

A quick proof-of-concept example:

```js
function changeLabel(select) {
  document.getElementById('field-label').innerHTML = select.value;
}
```

```css
#field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#field-label {
  color: blue;
}

#field-select {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div id="field-label">Click To Select</div>
  <select id="field-select" onchange="changeLabel(this)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select A Country</option>
    <option value="CAN">CAN - Canada</option>
    <option value="MEX">MEX - Mexico</option>
    <option value="USA">USA - United States</option>
  </select>
</div>
```